# Log radiobuttons value using angular constants

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new with Angular and need some help.

I have three radio buttons and I want to log in console the value of each one depending on the user selection, this is my controller:

```
    .controller('radioCtrl', function($scope) {
     .constant("data10","10")
     .constant("data20","20")
     .constant("data30","30")

    if(constant == data10){
        console.log(10);
    }else{
        if(constant == data20){
            console.log(20);
        }else{
            if(constant == data30){
                console.log(30);
            }
        }
    }
 })
```

And this is what I have in my view:

```
      <div class="radio" ng-controller="radioCtrl">
       <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="walmart" value="data10">Show top 10</label>
       <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="walmart" value="data20">Show top 20</label>
       <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="walmart" value="data30">Show top 30</label>
      </div>
```

Is my controller syntax okay or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the `console.log` to an event.

Use `ng-change` on your input and attach a function as the event handler that ultimately prints out the value you want.

Something like this:

```
<input ng-change="logger(val)" />
```

And then in your controller

```
$scope.logger = function(val){
   console.log(val)
}
```

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange